# target hamburger on hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hover, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to get the hamburger to turn white on hover but have been unable to target the element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title></title>
   <!-- CSS only -->
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <style media="screen">
      .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
         color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
      }

      button{
         border:none;
      }

      .navbar-toggler:focus {
         box-shadow: none;
      }

      .navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
         border:none;
      }

      .navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon:hover{
          background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
      }
   </style>


</head>

<body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">

            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link " aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
               </li>

            </ul>

         </div>
      </div>
   </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just needed to add quotes around the url data